# Is the Series : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} +\ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right) \sin^2 n\theta $ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is the Series :
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right) \sin^2 n\theta $$ convergent?

---

**Attempt**: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right) \sin^2 n\theta $$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right) (1- \cos( 2n\theta)) \frac 1 2$$

$$=\frac 1 2 \left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right)\right]- \frac 1 2\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right) \cos(2n\theta)\right] $$

The left part by sandwich theorem has limiting value to $0$

The right part by Dirichlets theorem is convergent as $  \left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right)$ is a positive, monotonically decreasing sequence and the sequence of partial sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos 2n\theta$ is bounded.

Hene, the given series is convergent. Am i correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $\theta=k\pi$, the series is  convergent.

If $\theta$ is not a multiple of $\pi$,

$$\left( \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} + \ldots+\frac 1 {(n+n)^2} \right) \sin^2 n\theta \geq \frac n{(n+n)^2}  \sin^2 n\theta =\frac {\sin^2 n\theta}{4n} =\frac1{8n}- \frac{\cos 2n\theta}{8n}$$

$\sum \frac{\cos 2n\theta}{8n} $ is convergent,  hence,  the series is divergent

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{(n+k)^2}=\frac 1{n}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right),$$
with $f(x):=\frac 1{1+x^2}$, a continuous positive function. Hence the convergence of the initial series reduces to the convergence of 
$$\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{\sin^2(n\theta)}n.$$
Write $\sin^2(A)=\frac{1-\cos(2A)}2$. If $\theta$ is not a multiple of $\pi$, the series is divergent because $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{\sin(2n\theta)}n$ is convergent.

Comment: Could you please explain the line "Hence the convergence of the initial series reduces to the convergence of .. "

Comment: If $(a_k)$ and $(b_k)$ are two sequences of positive numbers and $1/M\lt |a_k|\lt M$ for some $M$ and every $k$, then the convergence of $\sum_n a_nb_n$ is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum_n b_n$.